# fancybox callbacks

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have read over a dozen posts and answers ... to no avail.

What is wrong with this simple code, what am I missing here.
None of tried callbacks works.

```
$("#project_info").fancybox({
        'onComplete': function() {
            console.log('log this');
            //$.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
        }
    });
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click");
```

and html

```
<a id="project_info" href="#project_display"></a>
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="project_display" style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:auto;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
</div>
```

note: local wamp

edit: also tested on remote server - strip-down file to prevent any interactions - same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question, to post solution I finally used and tests performed. 
Maybe someone finds it useful.

There is something in fancybox 1.3 that kills callbacks, when cookie is used in them.

No time to test, what is it.

Anyone knows? write below.

Just a note: same happened, when I tried to set cookie via .trigger("click")
Callbacks work fine with standard click.

**What I tried - unsuccessfully.**

```
//trial 1: does not work
$("#project_info").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
    $.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
    }
});
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click");

//trial 2: does not work
function StoreCookie() { 
    $.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
} 
$("#project_info").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
    StoreCookie()
    }
});
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click");

//trial 3: does not work
function StoreCookie() { 
    $.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
} 
$("#project_info").fancybox({
    onComplete: StoreCookie
});
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click");

//trial 3: does not work
function StoreCookie() { 
    $.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
} 
$("#project_info").fancybox({
    //
});
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click", StoreCookie());//trial 1: does not work
$("#project_info").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
    $.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
    }
});
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click");

//trial 2: does not work
function StoreCookie() { 
    $.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
} 
$("#project_info").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
    StoreCookie()
    }
});
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click");

//trial 3: does not work
function StoreCookie() { 
    $.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
} 
$("#project_info").fancybox({
    onComplete: StoreCookie
});
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click");

//trial 3: does not work
function StoreCookie() { 
    $.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
} 
$("#project_info").fancybox({
    //
});
$("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click", StoreCookie());
```

**this I settled for**

I do not like it very much thou 
since cookie is stored somewhat outside of fancybox firing up

```
if (!$.cookie('fcookie')) {
    $("#project_info").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
        //
    }
    });
    $("#project_info").fancybox().trigger("click");
}
$.cookie('fcookie', '1', {path: ' / '});
```

Comment: I don't see what's behind the idea to store a cookie inside fancybox. What you could try is to call the cookie function `onClosed` rather than `onComplete`. That's true, fancybox cleans up after itself when closed.

Comment: that's what callbacks are for - to get something going (cookie is something); onClosed/onComplete - it does not work in neither; why cookie inside? I tried to use one fancybox instance for onload/click and setting/destroying cookies as needed - finally I used 2 - see here: http://tinyurl.com/cdldjrh

Answer (score 0):

The "onComplete" callback needs no quotes; You could do a simple:

```
$("#project_info").fancybox({
  onComplete: function() {
    alert('Completed!');
  }
});
```

Comment: I tested it both ways - no luck - there are so many complaints about fancybox callbacks, that it makes me wonder, if they are not only "we have it also" type of functionality - it is there - since others have it, but it seldom works - I also tested on remote server - same result

Comment: For fancybox v1.3.x quotes are actually recommended. Is not the case for v2.x